# How to make web installer for my Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know of @RachidLaasri/LaravelInstaller but it is rather a kind of different thing I want.

I want to do something like, go to a URL like localhost::8000/installer. Then, it will display a page for super admin registration, i.e., email, password, and username. Note: I want to eliminate the ability of making my superadmin app user going to the UsersTableSeeder to configure anything.

Then, when I click on install, it migrate my seeded classes. I currently watched the command line app but still can't really figure out how to go about this.

Any advice / tip will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[Laravel Installer](https://github.com/RachidLaasri/LaravelInstaller)

add 2 router in your project.

```
http : 
     routes.php
     routes2.php
---
view
    application/
    installation/
```

in first route you should take db name and more information you need from user. Save db name to .evn file.

After then you might create database using php codes, [How to make db Pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232901/pdo-creating-database-and-tables)
and run \Artisan::call('migrate') in your Controller.

Rename route to installation-route using [php rename method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) file. And rename route2 to route.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this [PHP Application Installer](https://github.com/JhulFramework/JI)

This library can be used for PHP appplication configuration(database, admin credentials etc) using user interface.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks for Advice